# Unable to perform npm install on react native project

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am working on a react native project and wants to install react navigation library for this I am trying to do npm install first but I am not able to do it.
**node version: v12.4.0

npm version: 6.9.0**
I am getting the following error:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@12.4.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:290:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:586:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node /Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node /Users/pankaj.sachdeva/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/pankaj.sachdeva/Desktop/HD/ReactNative/instaClone/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN @react-navigation/native@3.5.0 requires a peer of react-native-gesture-handler@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependenciesyourself.
npm WARN react-navigation-drawer@1.2.1 requires a peer of react-native-gesture-handler@^1.0.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-navigation-stack@1.4.0 requires a peer of react-native-gesture-handler@^1.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: What system are you using? Looks like a permissions issue on linux to me

Comment: I am using Mac.

Comment: Can you provide your package.json and the exact command you were trying to run as well?

Comment: I had this error a while ago. It originates from a python 2-3 mismatch. There's a [heated discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/193) about the subject with many pointers to potential fixes.